# Can I derive from classmethod in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators, class-method

I have a special statemachine implemented in Python, which uses class methods as state representation.

```
class EntityBlock(Block):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self._name = name

  @classmethod
  def stateKeyword1(cls, parserState : ParserState):
    pass

  @classmethod
  def stateWhitespace1(cls, parserState : ParserState):
    token = parserState.Token
    if isinstance(token, StringToken):
      if (token <= "generate"):
        parserState.NewToken = GenerateKeyword(token)
        parserState.NewBlock = cls(....)
      else:
        raise TokenParserException("....", token)
    raise TokenParserException("....", token)

  @classmethod
  def stateDelimiter(cls, parserState : ParserState):
    pass
```

Visit GitHub for full source code off [pyVHDLParser](https://github.com/Paebbels/pyVHDLParser).

---

When I debug my parser FSM, I get the statenames printed as:

```
State: <bound method Package.stateParse of <class 'pyVHDLParser.DocumentModel.Sequential.Package.Package'>>
```

I would like to get better reports, so I would like to overwrite the default behavior of `__repr__` of each bound method object.

Yes, I could write a metaclass or apply a second decorator, but I was questioning myself:
**Is it possible to derive from `classmethod` and have only one decorator called e.g. `state`?**

According to PyCharm's builtins.py (a collection of dummy code for Python's builtins), classmethod is a class-based decorator.

Comment: What is the reason to make these classmethods?  It makes `EntityBlock` effectively a singleton, but even if you only ever create one instance it seems more complex.  In particular, if you never create any instances, `__init__` will never be called.  If you do create instances, they will share state, which seems less useful.

Comment: This is a minimal example. EntityBlock will be created, otherwise it wouldn't have a `__init__` ... No they don't share a state, because the "state" is the method not the class. The class is a group of states in a hierarchical state machine. Anyhow, it doesn't answer my question, right?

Comment: Right.  My comment isn't on point for your question, I was just reacting to something that looked odd to me.

Comment: OK :) I linked the repo in my question. See this simple description of a [LIBRARY-statement](https://github.com/Paebbels/pyVHDLParser/blob/master/pyVHDLParser/Blocks/Reference/Library.py?ts=2).

Comment: What exactly do you want to put into your custom `__repr__` that isn't already there?  A "standard" classmethod doesn't have any internal state other than the string you're getting right now.  If you want the signature or something like that, use [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html).

Comment: My overloaded `__repr__` should e.g. return `Package.stateParse` or `Function.stateReadParams` so class plus method name. => I get it from the method `m` with `m.__func__.__qualname__`. I won't explain further how to handle states with functions and methods. a) it's not the question and b) it's state machine theory ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write your own class that derives from `classmethod` if you want. It's a bit complicated though. You'll need to implement the descriptor protocol (overriding `classmethod`'s implementation of `__get__`) so that it returns an instance of another custom class that behaves like a bound method object. Unfortunately, you can't inherit from Python's builtin bound method type (I'm not sure why not).

Probably the best approach then is to wrap one of the normal method objects in an instance of a custom class. I'm not sure how much of the method API you need to replicate though, so that might get a bit complicated. (Do you need your states to be comparable to one another? Do they need to be hashable? Picklable?)

Anyway, here's a bare bones implementation that does the minimum amount necessary to get a working method (plus the new `repr`):

```
class MethodWrapper:
    def __init__(self, name, method):
        self.name = name if name is not None else repr(method)
        self.method = method

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.method(*args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class State(classmethod):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.name = None
        super().__init__(func)

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = "{}.{}".format(owner.__name__, name)

    def __get__(self, owner, instance):
        method = super().__get__(owner, instance)
        return MethodWrapper(self.name, method)
```

And a quick demo of it in action:

```
>>> class Foo:
    @State
    def foo(cls):
        print(cls)

>>> Foo.foo
Foo.foo
>>> Foo.foo()
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.foo()
<class '__main__.Foo'>
```

Note that the `__set_name__` method used by the `State` descriptor is only called by Python 3.6. Without that new feature, it would be much more difficult for the descriptor to learn its own name (you might need to make a decorator factory that takes the name as an argument).

Comment: Comparison, pickling and hashing is not required. Does it have an impact on the performance? I mean on calling the method/state?

Comment: Calling the method via my a method wrapper like I wrote will certainly be slower than just using `classmethod`. It will add Python function call overhead twice to logic that already did one Python function call (for the method's actual code) and two builtin function calls (for the `classmethod.__get__` and the method object's `__call__`). How important that extra overhead is depends on how complicated the rest of the code is. If most of your state methods have only `pass` in their body and your program spends most of its time calling them, the performance hit may be large.